# What is causing a csv load error in weka?

Tags: csv, load, weka

Im receiving the following error when trying to open a CSV file in Weka version 3.8.5

> File not recognized as an 'CSV data files' file  Reason: wrong number
> of values. Read 2, expected 12, read Token [EOL], Line 2 Problem
> encountered on Line:2

I have read solutions to similar errors on this site and can't seem to find what is wrong with my particular file. However, as a very newbie weka user, it may just be my misunderstanding of the issue.  Can someone take a look at the sample csv data below and let me know if you see what I am not understnding or missing?

```
LossMonth,LossYear,ClaimNumber,PolicyNumber,ClaimBranch,Agency,LocationCounty,CATCode,CauseCode,IncurredLoss,CurrentReserves,"
City",State,ZIPCODE,"
COLLISIONTYPECD","
CLOSEDDT",DaystoCLose,"
FATALITYCNT","
FATALITYIND","
FAULTRATINGIND","
AUTOGLASSIND","
DEERLOSSIND","
WEATHERRELATEDIND","
POLICYTIERCD",ClaimStatus,AgencyHandled,VEHICLEYEAR,DRIVERRELATIONTOINSUREDDESC,TOTALLOSSIND,INSURANCESCORE,Age
10,2016,4125858,20169200,4,113,73,1,comp,2525,0,PADUCAH,KY,42001,x,42692,18,0,0,0,0,0,1,70,1,0,2004,Other third party,0,703,73
1,2018,4265645,20137828,13,106,37,1,hail,3164,0,BAGDAD,KY,40003,x,43214,88,0,0,0,0,0,0,50,1,0,2010,Named Insured,1,799,63
12,2016,4136759,20322058,5,105,105,1,hail,2547,0,GEORGETOWN,KY,40324,x,42713,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,1,0,2010,Named Insured,0,999,68
1,2016,4033032,20175699,13,106,106,1,comp,15327,0,SIMPSONVILLE,KY,40067,x,42469,73,0,0,0,0,0,1,80,1,0,2000,Named Insured,1,999,34
9,2016,4116782,20133146,2,115,115,1,wind,7529,0,SPRINGFIELD,KY,40069,x,42649,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,1,0,2003,Named Insured,0,783,47
2,2016,4038442,20170355,7,148,10,1,hail,3631,0,ASHLAND,KY,41101,x,42417,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,50,1,0,2010,Named Insured,0,778,42
2,2016,4039439,20218265,7,45,10,1,hail,3579,0,FLATWOODS,KY,41139,x,42444,25,0,0,0,0,0,0,40,1,0,2013,Named Insured,0,820,52
2,2016,4039440,20218265,7,45,10,1,hail,570,0,FLATWOODS,KY,41139,x,42422,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,40,1,0,2012,Named Insured,0,820,52
3,2018,4275810,20126522,15,40,40,1,hail,3747,0,LANCASTER,KY,40444,x,43216,55,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,1,0,2009,Named Insured,1,999,74
5,2016,4071936,20461965,15,40,40,1,hail,525,0,LANCASTER,KY,40444,x,42521,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,50,1,0,2006,Named Insured,0,999,68
3,2016,4046685,20226270,7,35,35,1,hail,3558,0,FLEMINGSBURG,KY,41041,x,42447,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,80,1,0,2012,Named Insured,0,842,69
4,2016,4055942,20439287,7,35,35,1,hail,2551,0,EWING,KY,41039,x,42475,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,70,1,0,2006,Named Insured,0,867,48
1,2016,4026514,20394097,7,148,10,1,hail,1350,0,ASHLAND,KY,41101,x,42376,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,40,1,0,2007,Named Insured,0,637,65
3,2016,4047152,20212062,15,141,76,1,hail,1739,0,BEREA,KY,40403,x,42473,27,0,0,0,0,0,0,80,1,0,2008,Named Insured,0,777,77
2,2016,4035512,20103029,15,40,40,1,hail,2008,0,LANCASTER,KY,40444,x,42405,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,2000,Named Insured,1,885,72
1,2016,4030456,20385643,15,120,40,1,hail,1497,0,LANCASTER,KY,40444,x,42450,62,0,0,0,0,0,0,20,1,0,2013,Named Insured,0,839,65
4,2016,4053299,20251610,5,69,11,1,hail,1535,0,DANVILLE,KY,40422,x,42514,48,0,0,0,0,0,0,100,1,0,2013,Insured,0,999,64
6,2016,4076264,20337992,17,140,1,1,hail,1799,0,MILLTOWN,KY,42728,x,42529,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,50,1,0,2002,Named Insured,0,999,84
8,2017,4217498,20596983,8,86,86,1,hail,660,0,TOMPKINSVILLE,KY,42167,x,42954,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,100,1,0,2012,Named Insured,0,999,45
1,2016,4026053,20511114,4,113,113,1,hail,1310,0,STURGIS,KY,42459,x,42376,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,100,1,0,2003,Named Insured,0,694,44
1,2016,4026766,20656586,4,113,113,1,hail,2360,0,MORGANFIELD,KY,42437,x,42383,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,20,1,0,2010,Named Insured,0,999,89
1,2016,4027473,20085251,6,42,42,1,hail,1699,0,MAYFIELD,KY,42066,x,42381,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,90,1,0,2008,Named Insured,0,747,50
1,2016,4029284,20167051,17,109,109,1,wind,3133,0,CAMPBELLSVILLE,KY,42718,x,42387,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,1,0,1993,Named Insured,0,886,78
1,2016,4031937,20326278,3,81,12,1,comp,3385,0,FOSTER,KY,41043,x,42402,8,0,0,0,0,0,1,40,1,0,2003,Named Insured,0,723,79
1,2016,4027931,20339366,8,107,107,1,wind,5858,0,FRANKLIN,KY,42134,x,42447,70,0,0,0,0,0,0,20,1,0,2014,Named Insured,0,940,80
1,2016,4028456,20453076,15,87,87,1,comp,2056,0,JEFFERSONVILLE,KY,40337,x,42387,7,0,0,0,0,0,1,100,1,0,2013,Named Insured,0,999,51
1,2016,4028597,20051661,4,113,113,1,hail,5320,0,WAVERLY,KY,42462,x,42712,332,0,0,0,0,0,0,20,1,0,2014,Named Insured,0,717,58
3,2016,4046687,20018268,6,42,42,1,hail,2736,0,MAYFIELD,KY,42066,x,42450,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,110,1,0,2012,Named Insured,0,735,73
9,2016,4116499,20128172,3,96,59,1,glss,320,0,TAYLOR MILL,KY,41015,x,42660,20,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1997,Spouse,0,923,81
1,2016,4026247,20086164,4,113,113,1,hail,1611,0,MORGANFIELD,KY,42437,x,42376,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,1,0,2013,Named Insured,0,902,61
1,2016,4027222,20033936,6,79,79,1,glss,105,0,CALVERT CITY,KY,42029,x,42389,14,0,0,0,0,0,1,110,1,0,2001,Named Insured,0,772,57
1,2016,4028311,20059964,4,75,75,1,comp,1040,0,SACRAMENTO,KY,42372,x,42382,2,0,0,0,0,0,1,10,1,0,1996,Named Insured,0,999,64
1,2016,4029164,20541039,6,42,42,1,wind,1495,0,SEDALIA,KY,42079,x,42382,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,2008,Named Insured,0,756,67
1,2016,4027475,20085251,6,42,42,1,hail,940,0,MAYFIELD,KY,42066,x,42381,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,90,1,0,2013,Named Insured,0,747,50
1,2016,4030356,20007300,4,117,117,1,hail,6550,0,DIXON,KY,42409,x,42436,49,0,0,0,0,0,0,40,1,0,2009,Named Insured,0,864,34
```

Comment: I've not used weka, but based on the `EOL` reference, could the newlines with the 10 lines after the first line possibly be the issue/trouble? It looks like those column names do not have spaces, so maybe quotes are unnecessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weka's CSVLoader cannot handle rows that span multiple lines (despite quoting). Once all your rows (header and data) are one per line, you should be fine.

The [common-csv](https://github.com/fracpete/common-csv-weka-package) (unofficial) Weka package should be able to handle rows spanning multiple lines.

Comment: Once I removed the leading spaces in all the header titles, they were reduced  to one line. I no longer got the error when opening.